# BasicAuthenticationAttribute triggers app.UseCookieAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I implement a custom `BasicAuthentiactionAttribute` for some Admin-Pages. Now i've implement the Asp.Net Identity for some Public-Pages. If I don't use the app.UseCookieAuthentication it works fine.

But if the `app.UseCookieAuthentication` is enabled and I navigate to a Page which is protected by `[BasicAuthentication]` the `app.UseCookieAuthentication` redirects to /Account/Login. Why? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by checking the area name in ApplyRedirect.

```
    private static void ApplyRedirect(CookieApplyRedirectContext context)
    {
        var dataTokens = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens;
        if (dataTokens.ContainsKey("area") && dataTokens["area"].ToString() == "Frontend")
        {
            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
        }
    }
```